# Deploying my first Django app to Heroku: Error message 'h12' status '503'

Tags: python, django, api, heroku, pythonanywhere

I'm working on my first app, and I've avoided having to ask any questions so far, but here we are at deployment.

Here is my code:
(Note: The majority of the program is in '/starWarsMeals/djangoStarWarsMeals/appStarWarsMeals/utils.py' and not 'models.py'. I didn't feel a database was my best choice for this app, as the 'swapi' API I am pulling data from may change. I figured it would be best to cache the results of the API vs. updating a database periodically.)

https://github.com/RyanLegits/starWarsMeals

I am trying to deploy my Django app to Heroku, but I get the following 'h12' error code:

https://textuploader.com/16beh

My suspicion is that the API calls at the beginning of the script in 'utils.py' are taking too long and causing Heroku to time out. However, I'd like a professional opinion before trying to refactor my code. Also, the last thing I changed in the app was setting the environment variables if that is helpful.

I tried deploying to Python Anywhere just to see if I could find anymore information. I got the 'Something went wrong' page and related error log:

https://textuploader.com/16bez

Notes:

I did make sure to change 'ALLOWED_HOSTS' in 'settings.py' for each attempted deploy. I tried setting it to 'localhost' for both Heroku and Python anywhere. After Heroku told me to change it to my Heroku app url, I did, and it seemed like the app would run, but that's when I received the 'h12' error code.

I understand I went crazy with camel case. I will be fixing that, as well as updating the code later. I'm just trying to get something online for now.

I have researched this error code, but many of this is over my head, as I jumped headfirst into this app.

I am using:
Django 3.0.3
Python 3.7
Everything in '/starWarsMeals/djangoStarWarsMeals/requirements.txt' (inside a virtual environment)

Any other code critiques are welcome!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's obvious that you have a long-running process that is taking more than 30 seconds (Heroku's limit) to return any data to the client.

> 2020-03-10 03:57:48,346:   File "/home/dreadPrivate/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/**init**.py", line 63, in _setup
>   2020-03-10 03:57:48,346:     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
>   2020-03-10 03:57:48,346: 
>   2020-03-10 03:57:48,347:   File "/home/dreadPrivate/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/**init**.py", line 161, in **init**
>   2020-03-10 03:57:48,347:     raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")

From your error logs, I noted that you don't have the secret key set. Have you set them in your environment variables or in `settings.py`, given that you also mentioned this above?

> Also, the last thing I changed in the app was setting the environment variables if that is helpful.

Comment: That's correct. I set the secret key as an environment variable path in 'settings.py'. However, the secret key is stored locally on my machine. Should it be placed somewhere else in the directory during deployment?

Comment: Put it in a `.env` file. It's always best to keep your secret key there than setting it in settings.py

Comment: Do you have a suggestion for finding out the specific long-running process and how I might go about handling this? I've seen Celery or multi-threading suggested, but those are both over my head at the moment, and I'd like to find another solution if possible.

Comment: I realized I did have the secret key in a local file, but set it in Heroku using 'heroku config:set <key>'. I had forgotten about this.

Comment: I believe the long-running process is due to the secret key not being set. In the error logs its continuously checking for the secret key and that execution exceeds the 30s, which then causes the h12 error. Try setting that and running it

Comment: I will see if I can configure it correctly and post back. Thank you!

Comment: I wasn't sure if I had my environment variables set correctly. I tried just hard-coding a key into my app and running Heroku with that, and I had the same issue. I am not sure what action to take next.

Comment: just place this `SECRET_KEY = '670b9a538dfe8545f4eff723345da43211084a05f520a2d638'` in `settings.py` and run it. If it doesnt then there's a big problem.

Comment: Yes, I tried doing just that and no success. I am going to try and remove the API calls from the app and see if it works.